# Manage DNS of subdomain for different server

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

So we have a global domain of example.com being and the DNS is managed on AWS Route 53.

I have a subdomain: sub.example.com

I want to be able to setup DNS failover using a different Route 53 account entirely.

Would I just go to the main DNS of example.com and create a Name Server record for sub.example.com pointing to the different name servers provided in Route 53 from the second account? This should allow me to manage the DNS for this subdomain within the secondary Route 53 account right?

Comment: (It is a bit unclear what do you mean by "DNS failover" here, but) Yes, you can delegate a sub-domain to other DNS servers, as you described.

Comment: Sorry, Route 53 has a failover system that you can use where it will check if A Record #1 is bad, if not getting response back from server, it automatically uses A Record #2 which would be a secondary server.

Comment: *"Would I just go to the main DNS of example.com and create a Name Server record for sub.example.com pointing to the different name servers provided in Route 53 from the second account?"*  Yes, that's exactly what you do. Details are in the answer to the linked question.  It doesn't matter whether the two hosted zones are in the same account or not.

Comment: Thank you for finding the duplicate post, I did not find that previously otherwise I would not have asked this question. Thank you both for your responses.